# PDF Comparison Check

Tags: .net, pdf, binary

I know that there are several ways of achieving this solution so I was hoping for some advice from anybody that might have implemented such a solution previously or anybody that has an idea.

I need to authenticate a PDF as 'unequivocally' genuine. I am currently tending towards providing an upload section on the web application and then using a binary check to authenticate it. The PDFs are originally generated by a web application and whilst the PDFs are generated/destroyed dynamically so I don't have access to the exact PDF that was originally generated, I can regenerate the PDF on demand.

My concerns are:

- Assuming all the settings are identical, would the PDF generating software theoretically generate binary identical PDFs each time?
- Would the PDF binary be changed (at all) by being sent as an email?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to authenticate a PDF as 'unequivocally' genuine

I think should not re-invent the wheel. You can use PDF Digital Signatures which were created for this purpose. Most PDF generating libraries support this feature.

> Assuming all the settings are identical, would the PDF generating software theoretically generate binary identical PDFs each time?

It depends on the "PDF generating software". While generating a PDF file sometimes unique IDs are needed, depending on how these IDs are generated you may or may not get identical files at a binary level.

> Would the PDF binary be changed (at all) by being sent as an email?

It should not, if it does it will probably get corrupt.

Answer (score 3):

No, the PDFs will not be binary identical: PDFs should contains their creation time (which will be different) and an ID (which should also be unique).